# Upper bound of the spectral norm of a matrix power

Tags: spectral-radius, matrix-norms

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a complex valued square matrix which can be written as $A=PUP$ in which $P$ is a projector and $U$ is a unitary matrix. The interesting case is $P$ and $U$ do not commute.

The matrix $A$ is not normal, and I would like to upper bound the 2-norm of $A^{n-1}$. It is the case that $\|A\|=1$, so an trivial upper bound is $\|A^{n-1}\|\leq\|A\|^{n-1}=1$. Is it possible to find a bound which is strictly less than 1?

I tried to read through some articles, e.g., this [thesis](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4691&context=etd), in particular, Chapter 3, but did not find an obvious approach.

Comment: If the spectral radius of $A$ is $1$ (as you write), then there is an eigenvalue of $A$ on the unit circle. This then also holds for any $A^k$. Hence also $\rho(A^{n-1})=1$ and thus $\|A^{n-1}\|=1$.

Comment: It is not necessarily the case $\|A^{n-1}\|=1$; we may take the answer by @Omnomnomnom as an example.

Comment: So, why do you write $\rho(A)=1$ in your question? This is not the case in Omnomnom's example.

Comment: Oh I see. But did you claim that $\rho(A)^k=\|A^k\|$? I am not sure if that is the case when $A$ is not normal.

Comment: Are they orthogonal projectors?

Comment: @user50394 No, I did not claim that. I just claimed what I wrote. Again, if $\rho(A)=1$, then $A$ has an eigenvalue on the unit circle, $Ax = ax$ with $|a|=1$. Hence $A^kx = a^kx$, so $A^k$ has the eigenvalue $a^k$, which is also on the unit circle. Consequently, $1 = \rho(A^k) \le\|A^k\|\le 1$ and therefore $\|A^k\|=1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks. You're right. Then I'll have to modify my question. I had observation that there exists an $x$ such that $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$ but such an $x$ cannot be an eigenvector in the problem I'm looking at.

Comment: @Geronimo Yes they are.

Comment: @user50394 I think it is even possible that $A^{n-1} = 0$, even if $P$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional.

Comment: @amsmath I think so. Taking U to be an $n$-cycle permutation matrix and P to be diagonal seems to give you $A^{n-1}=0$.

Comment: @user50394 Exactly. That's what I just found out. For example, take $P = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $U = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: @user50394 On the other hand, if $P$ maps to a subspace that is invariant under $U$, you have $\|A^k\|=\rho(A^k) = 1$ for all $k$. That's the other extreme, where $A$ is actually normal.

Comment: @amsmath That's right.

Answer (score 0):

Taking
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad U = \pmatrix{\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} & -\epsilon \\ \epsilon & \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2}}
$$
is enough for us to see that $\|(PUP)^{n-1}\|$ can be made arbitrarily close to $1$ in the case of $n = 2$.  A similar example works for arbitrary $n$.  That is, it's enough to take
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}}, \quad \pmatrix{U&0\\0&I_{n-2}}
$$
for sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: I would suspect, however, that it is possible to come up with a non-trivial bound which depends on $\|PU - UP\|$.

Comment: Thanks, @Omnomnomnom. I think I would view it as that if the projector is of rank one, then the upper bound is trivial. Perhaps a more interesting case to me is that if $P$ is of rank say $n-1$ then can we say something about the upper bound?

Comment: @user50394 the answer is still no.  If $\tilde P$ denotes the bigger projection matrix, consider $I - \tilde P$

Comment: Not sure if I understand it. Your answer seems to claim that $\|((I-P)U(I-P))^{n-1}\|=\|(PUP)^{n-1}\|$ but I don't see why that should be the case.

Comment: You should find that $(I-P)U(I-P)$ is a diagonal matrix.  Take it from there.

Comment: Never mind, I've made a mistake.  You're right